# Counter works for 1st post but not for 2nd post

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a JavaScript like counter that works on the 1st comment but the 2nd comment, I would appreciate any help given!

This keeps happening wether I use PHP or JavaScript, here is my JavaScript for the counter

```
var count = (function()
{
    var counter = 0;
    return function() {return counter +=1;}
})();

function displaycount()
{
    document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = count();
}
```

```
function getComments($conn)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id = $row['uid'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2); 

        if ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<div class='comment-box'><p>";
            echo $row2['first_name']."<br>";  
            echo $row['date']."<br>";   
            echo nl2br($row['message']);
            echo "<br>
                  <img src='image.ico' onclick='displaycount()'>
                  <p id='carrier'> 0 </p>";
            echo "</p>";

           if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
               if ($_SESSION['id'] == $row2['id']) {
                   echo "<form class='delete-form' method='POST' action='".deleteComments($conn)."'>
                             <input type='hidden'
                                    name='cid'
                                    value='".$row['cid']."'>
                             <button type='submit' name='commentDelete'>
                                 Delete
                             </button>
                         </form>";
               } else {
                   echo "<form class='edit-form' method='POST' action='replycomment.php'>
                             <input type='hidden'
                                    name='cid'
                                    value='".$row['cid']."'>
                             <input type='hidden'
                                    name='uid'
                                    value='".$row['uid']."'>
                             <input type='hidden'
                                    name='date'
                                    value='".$row['date']."'>
                             <input type='hidden'
                                    name='reply'
                                    value='".$row['reply']."'>
                             <button>Reply</button>
                         </form>";   
               }
           } else {
               echo "<p class='commentmessage'>You need to be logged in to reply</p>";
           }

           echo "</div>";     
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: what do you what to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that only the first comment is updating is you using the id **carrier** in all your comments.

The way to fixed this is:

1. Change the following line in your PHP code

   ```
   <p id='carrier'> 0 </p>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <p id="carrier-"'+$id+'"> 0 </p>
   ```

**Note**: try not expose the entity id, try to use another column in comment table, that is unique for each comment.

2. Change the click of the element, passing the column that you use in previous step, like this

   ```
   <img src='image.ico' onclick='displaycount('.$id.')'>
   ```
3. Change your javascript function to

   ```
   function displaycount(id) { 
        document.getElementById("carrier-"+id).innerHTML = count(); 
   }
   ```

If you have a question, please leave a comment

Comment: I tried the code that you had sent, and all I got was the number 14,15,15, I forgot to mention that I am using a table called comments so the comment's id's are 14,15,15, any other suggestions?

Comment: No, the c_id (comment_id) is not unique. Would making it unique yeild a different result?

Comment: you can try to create a random number, and pass this random number in place of the id